# How to reload environment variables during a chef run?

Tags: windows, chef-infra

I am automating some provisioning on windows using chef-solo. I have an issue with a recipe that needs an environment setup indirectly by a previous recipe (concretely, I am installing visual studio in recipe 1, and recipe 2 needs to start in a new environment to access the variables set up by recipe1).

As far as I know, there is no way to tell chef to 'reload an environment' ? What would be the best way to achieve this ? At worse, if that makes it easier, I don't mind rebooting either, as long as the reboot and chef continuning the provisioning is entirely automated.

Comment: Once I saw a solution that restarted only the chef run (on Linux) which had the desired effect of making the new hostname available in this cookbook: https://github.com/franco/chef-hostname

Comment: Unfortunately, that solution is based on fork semantics which I obviously cannot rely on here.

Comment: Please don't forget to mark an answer as correct! :)

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly run a ruby block and add the new environment variables to the current environment variables:

```
ruby_block "get new env variables" do
  block do
    new_env = `cmd.exe /C set`
    #do some parsing magic, then set the new_env
    ENV = parsed_env
  end
 end
```

I haven't tested this, but it may get you on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

Chocolatey uses `Refreshenv` script for the very same task, reloading environment variables from Registry.

I've ported this script to Ruby (licensed under Apache 2.0 license):

```
require 'win32/registry'

def get_reg_env(hkey, subkey, &block)
  Win32::Registry.open(hkey, subkey) do |reg|
    reg.each_value do |name|
      value = reg.read_s_expand(name)
      if block && ENV.key?(name)
        ENV[name] = block.call(name, ENV[name], value)
      else
        ENV[name] = value
      end
    end
  end
end

def refresh_env
  get_reg_env(Win32::Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment')
  get_reg_env(Win32::Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER, 'Environment') do |name, old_value, new_value|
    if name.upcase == 'PATH'
      old_value || File::PATH_SEPARATOR || new_value
    else
      new_value
    end
  end
end
```

You put it in `libraries` dir and use it in a recipe like this:

```
ruby_block 'refreshenv' do
  block do
    refresh_env
  end
  action :nothing
end

chocolatey_package 'visualstudio2017buildtools' do
  notifies :run, 'ruby_block[refreshenv]', :immediately
end
```

Maybe somebody could wrap it in a cookbook.

For more cross-platform way you could also take a look at [dotenv gem](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv).

Comment: That's really cool. There are a couple of things you might also consider as you enhance this - https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/blob/564a65235ea9b019fe0abbf3f9929b98da49ce5c/src/chocolatey/infrastructure.app/configuration/EnvironmentSettings.cs#L186-L275 (we need to go update the cmd and ps1 files to do more of this)

Comment: Looking at my script now, I see more important issue: how variables are expanded? If from current environment then it's wrong. And I'm not sure how Chocolatey deals with it. This script was one-time solution which I was ready to share. But it's better to be done in unified cross-platform solution like dotenv. See also https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/9741 for ongoing discussion on missing unifed way to set environment block in Windows apps